# QGIS 3 modeler: how to use the fields of an intermediate output as input in another algorithm?

Tags: qgis-modeler

I'm working on a model to calculate land uses (usos) in different areas (zonas):

[image]

I have corrected geometries, cutted the uses layer, corrected geometries again and used the fields calculator to assing the area ID to every uses polygon contained in it [geomintersects ('zonas', 'ID')]. After that, I want to use the "collect geometries" algorithm to summarize uses by code and area. However, none of the fields of this last output appears in the dialog box.

[image]

I have searched through the "input" window of the modeler without any success. How can it be done?

Comment: What is the tool used prior to collect geometries?

Comment: I have used the field calculator with "geomintersects ( 'areas', 'ID')", so the intermediate output has fields from both "original" layers.

Comment: I have edited the question. Hope it is clearer.